# Save disk on google disk

Tags: google-drive-api, storage, laravel-8

I need to store file from Storage::disk('local') to Storage::disk('google')
I try next code, but not working

```
$file = \File::get(storage_path('my/file.docx'));

\Storage::disk('google')->put($path, $file);
```

if I receive it from request, it work

```
\Storage::disk('google')->put($path, $request->file);
```

Can somebody help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you making a request to the Drive API?

Answer (score 0):

This is response for my question

```
\Storage::disk('google')->putFile($path, new File(storage_path('file.docx')), 'file.docx');
```